# CSS styles doesn't work for Html added by innerHtml in Angular 2+ directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to implement a simple loading icon directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLoading]',
})
export class LoadingDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() appLoading: boolean;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.appLoading) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'loading-wrap');
      this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHtml = '<div class="lds-ellipsis"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>';

    } else {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    }
  }

}
```

In my template I have:

```
<div [appLoading]="isLoading"></div>
```

But it looks like Angular doesn't apply my styles for loading spinner in styles.css for the content added into innerHtml. The styles work for the main element with class 'loading-wrap' though.

Comment: You mean lds-elliosis class style not being applied to innerHTML div?

Comment: @Chellappanவ yes, styles doesn't apply to lds-ellipsis, however, they apply to loading-wrap class

Comment: Sorry for the late replay can you  move your ids-ellipsis class  to style.css and check

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by `innerHtml`, it obviously should be `innerHTML`

```
this.elRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = '<div class="lds-ellipsis"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>';
```